# Lagrange polynomials with Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

This is the problem I have to solve:

> Write a program to evaluate and plot the Lagrange interpolant `Iu(x)` of `u(x) = 1/(1+x^2)` for `x` between `-5` and `5`. Do this for `5,7,9,11,13,15` point interpolants (5,7,9 etc. data points between, and including, -5 and 5). Your results should show both the function and the interpolant.

This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
int_pts = [5,7,9,11,13,15]; %various values for no. of point interpolants
n = length(int_pts);

u = @(x) 1./(1+x.^2); %the function we are interested in

numer = 1; 
denom = 1; %set initial values of numerator and denominator 

for k = 1 : n

    L = zeros( 1,int_pts(k) ); %create an array to store Lagrange polynomials 

    x = [-5 : 10/(int_pts(k)-1) : 5]; %create a list of x values

    udata = u(x); %create a list of corresponding values of u(x)

    for i = 1 : int_pts(k)

        if (i ~= k)

            denom = x(k) - x(i);

            syms z;
            numer = symfun( z - x(i) , z);        

            break

        end

        numer = numer * numer;
        denom = denom * denom;

        L(i) = numer / denom;

    end

end
```

I think I'm on the right track, but I'm really starting to become stuck with how to extract the data and plot everything nicely. I've searched everywhere but most code seems to only want to output the value of the Lagrange polynomial for certain numbers i.e. P(2)=...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, what you have developed has lead you on the right path to solving your problem.

Some of the small issues you are running into are:

**1) You are missing a `for` loop.**

In lagrange interpolation you should have a summation of n terms, where n is the number of data points you have.
And the terms are comprised of a product times the y component of the data point, i.e., yj*∏{(x - xi)/(xj - xi)}, where if i=j the term is skipped (this is done to make sure the denominator never is zero)

**2) Your inner `for` loop and `if` statement don't play well together.**

As soon as your script reaches the end of the `if` statement the `for` loop is broken and it continues to the next `k` value.

This should be replaced with a `else` followed by a `continue`.

**3) When you generate your `numer` and `denom` variables you are unintentionally just squaring the new value and storing it to the variable.**

You have `numer = numer * numer` this should be `numer = numer * numer_temp`

Here is a quick pseudo-code of the solution:

```
for n equals 'number of data points'

    Generate the n data points, P(x,y)

    for i equals 1 to n

        for j equals 1 to n

            if i is not equal to j
                Calculate Product of Numerators <- Function of x
                Calculate Product of Denominators
            else
                Continue to next iteration of loop
            endIf

        endFor

        Calculate Lagrange Polynomial < Function of x
    endFor

    Plot Lagrange
    Plot Original Function

endFor
```

And from this you can update your code to properly determine the Lagrange Polynomial.

```
u = @(x) 1./(1+x.^2); % The function we are interested in
number_of_data_Points = [5,7,9,11,13,15];


syms x; % Initializes x to be symbolic

for n = number_of_data_Points

    xn = linspace(-5,5,n);      % Creates x values
    yn = u(xn);                 % Creates y values

    L=0; % Re/Initializes Langrange Polynomial
    for j = 1:n
        numer = 1; % Re/Initializes Numerator
        denom = 1; % Re/Initializes Denominator
        for i = 1:n
            if j~=i
                denom_temp = xn(j) - xn(i);

                numer_temp = x - xn(i);    

                numer =  numer * numer_temp;
                denom = denom * denom_temp;
            else
                continue
            end
        end
        L = L + yn(j) * numer / denom;
    end
    L = matlabFunction(L);
end
```

I will leave changing the code, to output the results you require, to you.